# How can we set the SQL Server "Application Name" for a ColdFusion / jdbc driver?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, connection-string

SQL Server connection strings support a key-value pair named "Application Name".  Typically this would appear something like the following::

```
connString = "Data source=Mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=true;Application Name=MyAppName"
```

This value can then be accessed with the *APP_NAME()* function:

```
SELECT APP_NAME()

MyAppName
```

In our ColdFusion ".cfc" files, we're using jdbc:

```
, connectionString: 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://our.server.name:1433/abcde'
```

As I do not presently have access to a test/dev version of our application, I'm limited in the amount of experimentation I can do (essentially, 0%).

Adding to the **con**fusion, there is a ColdFusion "Application Name" string that appears in ".cfc" files, that may or may not map to the database "Application Name".  The Adobe pages I've found just name the setting without describing it.

So the question is: where should we enter the SQL Server "Application Name=" string, and what is the syntax (i.e. with or without the space, quoted or un-quoted)?

This has been difficult to research because searches find many references to the individual words but not as multi-word phrases.

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/discussion/104389/thread/2e36cd92/ Appending ";appName=MyApplication" after abcde should work

Comment: Just a note for you, the application.name variable you see in the CF code, that is a global variable to the Coldfusion code and definitely NOT part of any database information, unless specifically set up.

Comment: Aside... you're still using jTDS? It hasn't seen a release in [very nearly ten years](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/) and supports none of the TDS protocol features added to modern SQL Servers (post SQL Server 2012, on-prem and Azure).

Comment: Curious, what version of ColdFusion and SQL Server are you using?

Comment: THX for responses!
@AlwaysLearning - ColdFusion 2021 - I am not a CF developer myself, just trying to get "Application Name" set, so what driver for SQL Server would be more current for CF and what would the CF "connectionString" look like for that one?  And what would the CF developer "get" from using a more current driver?

Comment: @siggemannen I'll let you know if "appName=" works and then you can submit as an ANSWER if you like.